# Lego game with a trashcan eating robot

Tags: game-identification

I remember playing this game when I was really really young.  I think it was a flash game but I don't remember; I only have this screenshot of it saved from my old system.

[image]

Comment: Long shot but have you dragged the image into a Google Image Search?

Comment: @Timelord64 FYI: This gave a correct result.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lego Junkbot: http://thinking.goodgame.co.in/lego-junkbot-games.html

Lego Junkbot is an online 2d puzzle game where the aim is to lead the 'Junkbot' to eat all the trash cans on the level. The Junkbot only moves forward until it can no longer move forward, in which case it turns around and continues on. The player helps Junkbot to eat the trash by placing various bricks which modifies the path that Junkbot will take.

There are various levels with hazards that hinder the player in their task, such as fire and other robots.

Aside from completing the level by eating all the trash cans, another scoring system that is in place, is the number of moves required to complete the level, the fewer the better. Completing the level with the stated moves or less will result in a "gold award".

There's also a sequel: http://agility.goodgame.co.in/lego-junkbot-2-games.html

Comment: Nostalgia at its finest. I remember playing this game a lot.