# Lego Flash/Shockwave game with an Indiana Jones vibe from the early 2000s

Tags: game-identification

In the same vein as [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/227234/298317), I'm looking for an old browser-based Lego game, maybe Flash, maybe Shockwave, that I played more than ten years ago.

It was 2D, platformer-like, and puzzle-oriented. There were 3 characters on the map, and you could switch between them at any time (many puzzles revolved around getting one character somewhere and using another to perform an action, to open a door, etc). There were items to collect, maybe a shield and a sword. There were buttons that could open doors, and enemies to capture. The game itself didn't take more than 20 minutes to finish (for a child).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I'm unsure to see the point of a same-minute posted self-answered game-identification question. It can serve a purpose when it's a widely searched question on a known game, but I'm unsure that creating a self-answered question for this specific case is useful.

Comment: Sorry if this is off-topic, I checked the network guidelines beforehand and they seemed to suggest that self-answered questions were encouraged. Since I had quite some trouble finding information about this specific game, I figured that a question containing relevant keywords about the game's content could eventually be useful to someone looking for it.

Comment: It's not off-topic, is just unusual

Comment: If someone is downvoting this post because this is unusual then that's... rude, if I may say.

Answer (score 5):

The game is [LEGO Orient Expedition: The Quest for the Golden Dragon](https://stash.games/games/lego-orient-expedition-the-quest-for-the-golden-dragon), a Flash game released in 2003. It's now available in archival projects such as [BlueMaxima's Flashpoint](https://bluemaxima.org/flashpoint/downloads/).